Average and sum between two dates, from a daily data frame
I have a data frame with daily temperature data. I would like to calculate the average between two dates from a second data frame and add the results in a new column.
The average temperature must be calculated between the dates that are in the lines of data frame B.
Example:
average temperature between 02-15-2021 and 02-18-2021
average temperature between 02-18-2021 and 02-23-2021...
## Daily temperature data frame
date <- as.Date(c('02-15-2021', '02-16-2021', '02-17-2021', '02-18-2021',
                  '02-19-2021', '02-20-2021', '02-21-2021', '02-22-2021', 
                  '02-23-2021', '02-24-2021', '02-25-2021', '02-26-2021', 
                  '02-27-2021', '02-28-2021', '02-29-2021'), "%m-%d-%Y")
temp <- c(26, 27, 28, 30, 32, 27, 28, 29, 27, 26, 28, 29, 28, 25, 26)

A <- data.frame(date, temp)
head(A)

date2 <- as.Date(c('02-15-2021', '02-18-2021', '02-23-2021', 
                   '02-27-2021', '02-29-2021'), "%m-%d-%Y")

## Data frame with dates for average with the interval between dates to calculate
## the average temperature (the average between the #dates in the lines)

B <- as.data.frame(date2)
head(B)


Here one solution.
Perhaps not the faster (as could be with some table merge) but works and does not use external packages.
PD: changed '02-29-2021' as it is not a leap year.
#Daily temperature data frame
A <- data.frame(
 date = as.Date(c('02-15-2021', '02-16-2021', '02-17-2021', '02-18-2021', '02-19-2021', '02-20-2021', '02-21-2021',
                  '02-22-2021','02-23-2021','02-24-2021','02-25-2021','02-26-2021',
                  '02-27-2021','02-28-2021','03-01-2021'), "%m-%d-%Y"),
 temp = c(26,27,28,30,32,27,28,29,27,26,28,29,28,25,26))

B <- data.frame(
  date2 = as.Date(c('02-15-2021', '02-18-2021', '02-23-2021',
                  '02-27-2021','02-28-2021'), "%m-%d-%Y"))

# starts here
B$from <- B$date2
B$to <- c(B$date2[-1], Inf)

B$avg_temp <- 
  tapply(B, seq(nrow(B)), 
         function(x) {
           mean(A[A$date >= x$from & A$date < x$to,]$temp)})

B
#>        date2       from         to avg_temp
#> 1 2021-02-15 2021-02-15 2021-02-18     27.0
#> 2 2021-02-18 2021-02-18 2021-02-23     29.2
#> 3 2021-02-23 2021-02-23 2021-02-27     27.5
#> 4 2021-02-27 2021-02-27 2021-02-28     28.0
#> 5 2021-02-28 2021-02-28        Inf     25.5


An easy way could be to cut A$date usng B$date2 as breaks.
> with(A, aggregate(list(ave_temp=temp), list(max.date=cut(date, B$date2)), mean))
    max.date ave_temp
1 2021-02-15 27.00000
2 2021-02-18 29.20000
3 2021-02-23 27.50000
4 2021-02-27 26.33333

Note that each date is included only once:
> transform(A, group=as.integer(cut(date, B$date2)))
         date temp group
1  2021-02-15   26     1
2  2021-02-16   27     1
3  2021-02-17   28     1
4  2021-02-18   30     2
5  2021-02-19   32     2
6  2021-02-20   27     2
7  2021-02-21   28     2
8  2021-02-22   29     2
9  2021-02-23   27     3
10 2021-02-24   26     3
11 2021-02-25   28     3
12 2021-02-26   29     3
13 2021-02-27   28     4
14 2021-02-28   25     4
15 2021-03-01   26     4

'02-29-2021' doesn't exist, since we'd get NA I've changed A to 2021-03-01 and B to 2021-03-02 to be one day larger.

Data:
> dput(A)
structure(list(date = structure(c(18673, 18674, 18675, 18676, 
18677, 18678, 18679, 18680, 18681, 18682, 18683, 18684, 18685, 
18686, 18687), class = "Date"), temp = c(26, 27, 28, 30, 32, 
27, 28, 29, 27, 26, 28, 29, 28, 25, 26)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
> dput(B)
structure(list(date2 = structure(c(18673, 18676, 18681, 18685, 
18688), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

